# Render or convert proprietary-encoded characters that use custom fonts for HTML

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts, pdf.js

I have extracted characters from PDFs that require custom fonts to render.

I can render the characters OK in SVG, but I need to render them in HTML (as SVG made old mobile browsers laggy and battery hungry).

However if I render the same characters as HTML with the custom font face, they render as, for example ``` M¿’ƒ” T¡u``  ̈ÃU uìÒ SkuM“  M¿ ```. I think this is because the fonts use proprietary encodings?

To see this, click the "Text only" checkbox on this [page](https://ethiopialearning.com/content/page?id=22632), and it will replace the correct server-side render with the incorrectly rendered characters.

(For now, I have included the ineffective CSS referencing the font files (extracted from the PDF using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js)), but I'll disable this after a week or two.)

However if you go to the [first page](https://ethiopialearning.com/content/page?id=22622) of that book, you can see that standard fonts in the same alphabet (Fidel, from Ethiopia) render OK, presumably as it is not using proprietary encodings.

Is there any way I can get those proprietary encodings rendering in HTML? Either by preprocessing/decoding the source characters (ideally Python or Node, as I'm already using them, but anything - I am pretty desperate), or doing something to help the browser render them?

Thanks

Comment: I don't work with fonts like that, so this may be a long shot, but I downloaded this [OTF](https://el1.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/6e/d8ecd69a3ffa68405d24d6ef491d17de91f52bf6c78265471a34c097d64905.otf) file referenced in the CSS and opened it in W10 and noticed that the official name is *GFAJAO+Geez1Normal*. Shouldn't you be using that name as `font-family`?

Comment: Thanks very much for the idea. I have tried that, using various means of quoting the font name in the CSS and span, but not managed to get it working. I don't think it is necessary as font names can contain characters that are not valid as CSS font names, such as apostrophes, so you name the font face in the CSS and use that. Also, if you detach the CSS from the span, the font does change (in my browser to the default serif), so it does seem to be applying *something*. Happily corrected though if I've missed something.

Comment: I just rememebered, maybe the [Google 'Noto' font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) ('Roboto' like) is an option for you. It is specially designed for use with a huge list of Asian languages and [Google Fonts has 12 families](https://fonts.google.com/?query=noto) online.

Comment: Have you tried using the original characters in your HTML elements instead of the *pdf.js* converted text? Checkout the source of some Japanese site for example and you will see real Japanese characters in the HTML. The point with your problem is that apparently HTML does find characters in the OTF, otherwise it would show little squares with a 4-digit hex value. (A character in some text is nothing more that a 4-digit index number into the list of characters (read 'table') in the font-file. Intriguing puzzle, can't stand not knowing the solution. Keeps me digging....

Comment: Thanks very much for your persistence! The original PDF [is here](http://files.ethiopialearning.com/Social%20Studies%20in%20Amharic%20Grade%205%20Student%20Book.pdf). If I copy the text out of the PDF into a Word doc I get the same nonsense output. If I then set it to the font, the correct characters appear. This even works if I copy the `M¿’ƒ” T¡u``  ̈ÃU uìÒ SkuM“  M¿` string from above. So I think somehow it is not picking up the correct glyph from the font file. But I'm out of my depth at this point tbh.

Comment: If I view source in developer tools of the working text on the first page, the correct characters appear, presumably rendered as unicode Sans Serif, which seems to contain the alphabet too. (You need to view the source in developer tools, as the spans are generated by Javascript, although this is not the cause of the issue as I've experimented with plain HTML too.)

Comment: I am wondering if I can add an offset to each individual character code to make it render in a non-proprietary character set font, but I don't have the first clue how I'd map one to the other!

Comment: Oddly, rendering it as text elements inside SVG worked fine, but I had to abandon that approach as zooming, panning, etc became laggy even on modern phones, let alone the old ones most of my users use.

Comment: The full font file [is here](https://files.ethiopialearning.com/Ge'ez-1.ttf) - the ones extracted from the PDFs are partial (but are the ones used by the PDF so should cover the characters needed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219044/discussion-between-rene-van-der-lende-and-chris).